# Converting Everything to Unicode

Tags: python, encoding

What is the difference here? Why does one seem to work sometimes whereas the other does not?

```
''.join(unichr(i) for i in bytearray(string)) # vs unicode(string) which crashes sometimes
```

Shouldn't they both successful turn a bytestring into a unicode string without throwing any errors?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Like yesterday, if `string = 'hello \xab'`

Comment: `unicode` expects all its characters to be `0 <= ord(i) <= 127` while `unichr`'s docs say "Return a Unicode string of one character with `ordinal i; 0 <= i <= 0x10ffff`."  (or 0 <= i <= 0xffff). `\xab` has ordinal 177

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Walking through your example:

```
bytearray(b'hello \xab')
```

is nothing but an array of bytes with the following values:

```
>>> s = bytearray('hello \xab')
>>> for x in s:
...     x
... 
104
101
108
108
111
32
171
```

`unichr` takes the *number* of a *Unicode code point* (within a constricted range, see @AdamSmith's comment) and returns the corresponding Unicode character. The interesting byte in your example is 171. Unicode code point 171 (or in hex: U+00AB) maps to the character « (aka Left-pointing double angle quotation mark).

Remember that Unicode is not an encoding of Unicode characters to bytes. At its core, Unicode is just a mapping of integers to characters. Integer 171 happens to be mapped to the character «, so that is what `unichr(171)` gives you.

```
>>> print(unichr(171))
«
>>> u'\u00ab'
u'\xab'
>>> print(u'\u00ab')
«
```

`unicode(somestring, encoding)` will attempt to **decode** bytes to Unicode code points using a specific encoding (default is ascii). The key thing to note here is that not all sequences of bytes are valid ascii, utf-8, utf-16, and so on.

```
>>> unicode('hello', encoding='ascii')
u'hello'
```

No problem, 'hello' can be decoded using ascii.

```
>>> unicode('hello \xab', encoding='ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Oops, we can't decode the byte \xab using ascii, because it is out of ascii's range (as the error message suggests).

```
>>> unicode('hello \xab', encoding='utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position 6: invalid start byte
```

As you can see, utf-8 will fail too, because as I said not every sequence of bytes is valid utf-8.

In summary:

- `unichr` takes the number of a code point and gives you the corresponding unicode character
- `unicode` attempts to decode bytes into unicode code points according to a specific encoding

In response to the comment:

> So if you wanted to definitively convert to unicode without a chance of error would you suggest `unichr`

No, your usage of `unichr` will give completely wrong results. Consider the following example using unicode snowman:

```
>>> bytestr = u'☃'.encode('utf-8')
>>> bytestr
'\xe2\x98\x83'
>>> unicode(bytestr, encoding='utf-8')
u'\u2603'
>>> print(unicode(bytestr, encoding='utf-8'))
☃
>>> ''.join(unichr(x) for x in bytearray(bytestr))
u'\xe2\x98\x83'
>>> print(''.join(unichr(x) for x in bytearray(bytestr)))
â
```

Comment: No, `''.join(unichr(x) for x in bytearray(string))` will give you completely different results than `unicode(string, encoding=the_right_encoding)`. The unichar version just produces a wrong result most of the time, you *need* to know your encoding.

Comment: So let me `\xab` could result in different characters depending on the original encoding?

Comment: Next iteration of Python should take a hint from Swift as far as encoding goes.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi yes, for all you know \xab could mean flying cow according to FCE-8 (flying cow encoding) which I just invented.

Comment: Okay, I completely understand. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert an 8-bit bytestring to Unicode, you need to specify the encoding of that data, because there are many different encodings that might have been used. Python's `unicode` constructor will, by default (in Python 2) use the `"ascii"` codec for decoding, which will not be able to decode any value that uses the highest bit, since ASCII is a 7-bit encoding.

Try using `unicode(string, encoding)` or the perhaps more explicit `string.decode(encoding)` where `encoding` is the encoding of your data. Using the `"latin-1"` encoding will work exactly the same as your `unichr` code, since the lowest 256 characters of Unicode are the same as the 8-bit Latin-1 character set. Whether that is actually correct for your data is something I can't guess.